# Is it legal to download google chrome from Linux mint software manager?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, chrome, google

when I download google chrome I see this.......
**NOTE: This wrapper is not verified by, affiliated with, or supported by Google.**
What does it means? Is it legal to download google chrome from Linux mint software manager?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it legal to download google chrome from Linux mint software manager?

Yes, it is absolutely legal to install Chrome through the software manager.

---

Google Chrome only official distributes Chrome packages from https://www.google.com/chrome/, where you will find links for both apt (debian/ubuntu) and rpm (fedora/rhel/etc) based system.

You are installing Chrome through a convenience mechanism provided by the Flathub repository. This makes Chrome available via the software manager, so it can be installed (and updated) using the same package management tools you use for other packages.

Google doesn't provide Chrome via Flathub; this is something done by volunteers who have contributed their time and effort to try to make the installation experience more seamless.

Comment: NOTE: This wrapper is not verified by, affiliated with, or supported by Google.                       What does it means? is it permitted by google?

Comment: Google permits redistribution of Chrome. They don't *support* distribution via Flathub (or anything other than the official download site, as indicated in my answer). So, yes, this is permitted by Google, but if you ran into installation problems you would not expect to go to Google for support.